# FreeMarker App-Engine example

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, freemarker

Does anyone have a FreeMarker Google App-Engine example they don't mind sharing? I am coming from Jinja2 on Python App-Engine and am migrating to Java App-Engine. Someone here finally recommended FreeMarker. But I cannot find any example on how to use it on an App-Engine project. Imagine a very simple app-Engine project with a Hello World servlet. How would I incorporate FreeMarker into this project?

1. Where does the `html` template go?
2. How do I access it from inside the servlet and pass it to FreeMarker?

So far I have the Gradle import done:

```
compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.14'
```

Comment: You should chose a web application framework first. How to integrate FreeMarker depends on that. BTW, "2.3.14" is an ancient version; use the latest one ("2.3.24-incubating" ATM).

Comment: 2.3.24-incubating has a GAE specific build, as detailed on their release page, you'll need to use that one. After that, following a basic how to should get you there.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Are you saying I should use `2.3.24` instead of `2.3.14`? Do you have a link to where it says `2.3.24` is GAE compatible? btw I have found tutorials on how to use FreeMarker. Thanks!

Comment: http://freemarker.org/freemarkerdownload.html